# IDEA выделяет features, хотя реализация шагов есть и тесты работают

Tags: java, cucumber, selenide

Создал простой проект Selenide + Cucumber, написал feature-файл и реализацию шагов. Тесты работают но в feature-файле идея подсвечивает что шаг не реализован и не позволяет перейти к реализации. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

POM:

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>dependency:copy-dependencies test</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <selenide.headless>true</selenide.headless>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Feature:

```
@all
Feature: Test CoopLand page

Scenario: Open page
Given test
Then Check it
```

Steps:

```
public class CoopLandSteps {
@Given("test")
public void test() {
    open("https://coop-land.ru/");
}
@Then("Check it")
public void check_it() {
    if (!$(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div[2]/div/a/img")).is(Condition.exist)) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
    $(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"story\"]")).setValue("TEST");
}
}
```

Runner:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report","json:target/cucumber-report.json"},
    features = "src/test/java/features",
    glue = "steps",
    tags = "@all",
    dryRun = false,
    strict = true
)
public class BaseRunner {

@Rule
public TestRule report = new TextReport().onFailedTest(true).onSucceededTest(true);

@BeforeClass
static public void setup() {
    Configuration.headless = true;
    Configuration.browser = "chrome";
    //Configuration.holdBrowserOpen = true;
    Configuration.startMaximized = true;
    Configuration.reportsFolder = "target/surefire-reports";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это всего лишь несовершенство плагина Cucumber для IDEA.

Попробуйте в аннотациях @Given и @Then названия сценариев оформить как регулярное выражение вот так:

```java
public class CoopLandSteps {
  @Given("^test$")
  public void test() {
    open("https://coop-land.ru/");
  }

  @Then("^Check it$")
  public void check_it() {
    if (!$(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div[2]/div/a/img")).is(Condition.exist)) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
    $(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"story\"]")).setValue("TEST");
  }
}
```

Мне помогло. Если не выйдет - смело создавайте issue в поддержке IDEA